# Why do I need Content/Type variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, content-type

In my MVC Core application, I have in my controller a way for the user to download an image that I have saved which is called from a button click in my view. I don't understand why I need the second variable "contentType" string in my return File(). I can still download the image as a .jpg if I put in "application/pdf" instead of "application/jpg", so what is even the point of having it other than the fact that it is required. What is the point of this variable?

```
public FileStreamResult Download()
    {
        string filename = "Capture.JPG";
        string filepath = hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath + "\\Image";
        string fullName = Path.Combine(filepath, filename);
        return File(new FileStream(fullName, FileMode.Open), "application/pdf", filename);
    }
```

Comment: So that it knows what kind of file to return.  I'm not an expert on this, but I would imagine this is how (in part) you tell the browser to differentiate a file from just another web page, and the browser is smart enough to know what to do with different file types.

Comment: Further, files can be similar enough where some operations (e.g. downloading the file) might work for both.  But many browsers have preview capabilities, and that will break if you try to preview a PDF in a browser that's expecting a JPG.

Comment: But then I don't understand why application/zip or application/json would still work since those are very different?

Comment: As I said, if you're just downloading the file, the browser doesn't really care what kind of file it is.

Comment: The code needs to know type like : binary, xml, text, or json so server know how to decode and it the type is encoded (base64 string).  It probably doesn't matter what type of binary if it is jpg or pdf.  But does need to know when it is other types.

Comment: Oh okay, so to summarize, that is more important for use cases other than just downloading a file (or for more "difficult filetypes")

Comment: The browser (aka "user agent") can look at the content type and decide how it should be interpreted.  For example, if you download a PDF file (`"application/pdf`), the browser may download the file and fire up a PDF viewer, for example, or an image viewer for `application/pdf`.  The server can lie, but the browser expects it to tell the truth and may be using that information to do something specific for the content type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flydog's comment is quite pertinent; perhaps the most useful or obvious difference you'll find in declaring a content type is that the browser may use it to invoke a different behavior depending on the setting. If you send an mp4 video as "video/mp4" the browser may well play it within its viewport. If you send the same file as "application/octet-stream" it may offer a save as. If you claim one content type and it's actually another it's likely the browser will ignore you (note: claiming a pdf is pdf or octet stream are both reasonable/true. Claiming it's a jog is not). Content-Disposition also plays a part in the server aiming to give the browser some direction on what to do with the file..

..but primarily I'd say a good reason to tell the truth about the content type (ie don't claim it's a jpg when it's a pdf) is the interop mantra "when it sones to standards adherence, be strict in what you send and liberal in what you accept" - you're sending, so follow protocol :)